# R shiny: Updating mulitple areas of the interface with single renderUI

Tags: shiny

I am creating a shiny dashboard. I have a single selectInput that will update multiple places in the UI. Currently I am having to us multiple renderUI functions to do this. I was wondering whether there was a way to only use 1.  For example I have this:

```
output$fig_con_1 <- renderUI({
      commodity_impact_graph(l_impact_val)
    })
output$tab1 <- renderUI({
      includeHTML(wetland_path)
    })
output$tab2 <- renderUI({
      includeHTML(river_path)
    })
```

I wish to achieve something akin to this:

```
output[all areas of the UI] <- renderUI({
      commodity_impact_graph(l_impact_val)
      includeHTML(wetland_path)
      includeHTML(river_path)
})
```

Comment: use `tagList()` to include the three elements inside your renderUI.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not clear. I want to consolidate the 3 render UIs into one. Note that each renderUI is associated with a different part of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
output$all <- renderUI({
  tagList(
    commodity_impact_graph(l_impact_val)
    includeHTML(wetland_path)
    includeHTML(river_path)
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks but this wouldn't work as there are 3 different areas to the page, namely fig_con_1, tab1 and tab2.

Comment: How does one associate say commodity_impact_graph to fig_con_1 using this method?

Comment: Sorry, without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is not possible to test your requirements.